# C# refund SQL syntax

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I wrote an inventory software; I have 3 forms 1st one had items to inventory 2nd one sell items from inventory and the last one we can refund the items we sold.

I have problem with the refund command, here is the code:

```
try
{
    mycon.Open();
    int y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Pharmacy_Items Set Quantity= Quantity + " + dataGridView1.Rows[y].Cells[4].Value + " , Sold= Sold - " + dataGridView1.Rows[y].Cells[4].Value + " where ItemName='" + dataGridView1.Rows[y].Cells[1].Value + "'", mycon);
        cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
        y += 1;
    }

    mycon.Close();
}
```

With this code I want to add the items to stock again but sometime it doesn't work and it didn't add items and change the items not right. Is there anything wrong with my code or the way I am using?

Thanks

Sorry for bad English : )

Comment: Use parameterized queries.

Comment: @gordonLinoff Can you show me please with the codes, sorry i am new : )

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you show me please with the codes, sorry i am new : )

Comment: I would start by putting your command into new variable `strCommand` and then `Debug.WriteLine(strCommand);`. followed by `SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(strCommand, mycon);`. That way you can check each update command is valid.  Also, does the code ever throw an exception? If it does, the remainder of your update statements won't be executed.

Comment: @JohnD no it doesnt throw any exception but sometime it gives good result sometime it doesnt and it missed up all updated items.

Answer (score 2):

Use a parameterized query which is more readable and recommended way.

```
try
        {
            mycon.Open();
            int y = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                string sql = "UPDATE [dbo].[Pharmacy_Items] Set Quantity= Quantity + @Quantity , Sold= Sold - @Sold where ItemName=@ItemName";

                using (SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(sql, mycon))
                {
                    cmd5.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    var qunatityParam = new SqlParameter{Value=dataGridView1.Rows[y].Cells[4].Value, SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Int, ParameterName="Quantity"};
                    var soldParam = new SqlParameter{Value=dataGridView1.Rows[y].Cells[4].Value, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, ParameterName = "Sold"};
                    var itemNameParam = new SqlParameter{Value=dataGridView1.Rows[y].Cells[1].Value,SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterName = "ItemName"};

                    cmd5.Parameters.Add(qunatityParam);
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add(soldParam);
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add(itemNameParam);
                    cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                y += 1;
            }
            mycon.Close();
        }
```

Or the better way is write a stored procedure in SQL end and call that from your C# code as below which prevents SQL injection.

**SQL**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EditPharmacyItems 
    @Quantity INT,
    @Sold INT,
    @ItemName VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Pharmacy_Items 
    SET Quantity = Quantity+@Quantity 
    ,Sold = Sold - @Sold 
    WHERE ItemName =@ItemName
END
GO
```

**C#**

```
            try
            {

                string sqlQuery = "[dbo].[EditPharmacyItems]";
                int y = 0;
                mycon.Open();

                for (int i = 0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, mycon);
                    cmd5.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    var qunatityParam = new SqlParameter{Value=dataGridView1.Rows[y].Cells[4].Value, SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Int, ParameterName="Quantity"};
                    var soldParam = new SqlParameter{Value=dataGridView1.Rows[y].Cells[4].Value, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, ParameterName = "Sold"};
                    var itemNameParam = new SqlParameter{Value=dataGridView1.Rows[y].Cells[1].Value,SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterName = "ItemName"};

                     cmd5.Parameters.Add(qunatityParam);
                     cmd5.Parameters.Add(soldParam);
                     cmd5.Parameters.Add(itemNameParam);
                     cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();                
                     y += 1;
                }
                mycon.Close();
            }
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot upvote this answer because it uses `AddWithValue()`.  That makes it a bad example for people learning how to use parameters.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It was a mistake. Edited the answer appropriately.

Comment: Why you create SqlCommand for each cycle pass? you can create it one time right after myconn.Open() and inside cycle body just fill parameters value and ExecuteNonQuery.